# How to train syntaxnet model with my own POS data?

Tags: tensorflow, pos-tagger, syntaxnet

I have my own POS data with below format.

**Sentence:**

> I love Stack Overflow.

**POS:**

> I/PRP love/VBP Stack/NNP Overflow/NNP ./.

So, how I train Syntaxnet with this data?

And also I want to get this output:

```
**(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP I))
    (VP (VBP love)
      (NP (NNP Stack) (NNP Overflow)))
    (. .)))**
```

What is the format of **"record_format: 'english-text'"** in Syntaxnet context.pbtxt file? How its look like?

Answer (score 0):

The output that you are interested in is a constituency parse tree. I am afraid you won't be able to use SyntaxNet to produce constituency trees without some significant code changes.

For POS tagging only, please use the CoNLL format where you fill in only columns 1, 2 and 5:
http://ilk.uvt.nl/conll/#dataformat

Comment: what type of changes i have to make?